# Download audio from Parse and save it into your device

Tags: swift, audio, parse-platform

I am quite new to swift. I am trying to download an audio that I have stored in Parse as .caf and want to be able to save it in my iPhone. I have tried something similar I used with images but obviously it is not working. Here is the code:

```
func saveAudio(name: String, audio: PFFile) {
    var documentsDirectory:String?
    var audioSave: NSData = NSData()

    let paths:[AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

    if (paths.count > 0){

        documentsDirectory = paths[0] as? String
        audio.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
            if let data = data where error == nil{
                audioSave = NSData(data: data)
            }
        })
        let savePath = documentsDirectory! + "/" + name
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(savePath, contents: audioSave, attributes: nil)
    }
}
```

audio in this function is the object["audiophile"] stored in Parse.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the data *in the background*, which means that your `audioData` variable may or, more likely, may not have valid data in it when your `createFileAtPath` method is being called.

Call `createFileAtPath` from **WITHIN** the background block, after the data has been successfully retrieved.

Something like this perhaps?

```
documentsDirectory = paths[0] as? String
        audio.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                if let data = data {
                   audioSave = NSData(data: data)
                   let savePath = documentsDirectory! + "/" + name
                   NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(
                     savePath, contents: audioSave, attributes: nil)
                }
            } else {
                print("got some kind of error - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
```